# Popup dialog/alert box from BackgroundService

Tags: java, android, native

How to popup alert box or dialog when android app is running in BackgroundService ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. If your app isn't in the foreground, your dialog interrupts what the user is actually doing, which is hostile. Post a [notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) instead.

Comment: Oh, thanks for this it is really useful but in many other apps there alert/dialog boxes when app is closed, so I would really like to know how they do it.

Comment: Look into IntentServices. You can execute asynchronously and post notifications without having a UI.